# How to get data just from one channel using python and alsaaudio

Tags: python, audio, pyalsaaudio

I am using python 3 and with alsaaudio I read data from microphone but I have to work with each channel separately. So is there a way how to get data just from one channel? Or how to parse data from each channel separately?

```
import wave
import sys
import threading
import time
import os
import alsaaudio, audioop

# Input 
inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE,alsaaudio.PCM_NONBLOCK)
inp.setchannels(2)
inp.setrate(8000)
inp.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
inp.setperiodsize(80)

# Output file
output = wave.open("test2.wav",'wb')
output.setnchannels(2)
output.setsampwidth(2)
output.setframerate(8000)

while True:
    l,frames = inp.read()
    if l>0:
        print(frames)
    output.writeframes(frames)
```